# What is best way to develop if project in ASP.NET Core and Web API is in ASP.NET MVC (Framework)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dynamics-365

I am not sure whether I need to post this confusion over here but I am confused. I am working on a project. There is a website (frontend), MS Dynamics 365 (backend) and Web API (mediator service). The Web API is used to get data from MS Dynamics 365 using MS Dynamics SDK (DLL) and show it on the website.

**Concern**: the website is using ASP.NET Core. I want to develop a Web API in ASP.NET Core but the [Nuget](https://xrmdynamicscrm.wordpress.com/2020/07/19/connect-to-dynamics-crm-online-using-net-core-sdk/)(DLL) is in alpha stage. The Nuget is important and it is for authentication. It is difficult to trust and plan for long term development based on alpha version. The DLL is stable for the full .NET Framework.

Alternatively, I could develop the website in ASP.NET Core and the Web API in the full ASP.NET Framework. This way I can achieve the goal but I need to host Web API on a Microsoft Server.

**Thought**: can I manage something in single project with single hosting by using ASP.NET Core website and Web API in the full ASP.NET Framework?

Please suggest your thoughts.

Comment: I see absolutely no reason why this wouldn't work. You can easily have an ASP.NET Core MVC website project, and an ASP.NET Web API project both in the same Visual Studio solution. The communication between them is strictly based on HTTP and REST - so that's totally independent of any underlying platform choice. So I'd say: **just go for it!** and don't let doubts hinder you - just do it !

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the quick advice. `1- You mean Website in ASP.NET Core and API is in ASP.NET Web API(.Net Framework) under same Solution?` `2- Can I publish Web API project in Linux Server?`

Comment: The full .NET Framework (v4.7.x or v4.8) runs **only** on Windows. So if you create your Web API using the full .NET framework, it **must be hosted** on a Windows Server (typically in IIS)